# Spring AOP ProxyFactory class - how to retrieve original bean property value

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to understand the behaviour of

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory
```

So the problem I have encountered is (simplified to remove confidential info)

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    public A(B b) {
        System.out.println(b.num);
    }
}

@Repository
public class B {
    public int num = 10; 
}
```

Where above prints 0 rather than 10.
After some investigation I have come to

```
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization
```

where it apply bean processors to this bean (B), the processor that wiped out the value in "b.num" is

```
PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
```

and I digged into that and got to

```
AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization
```

specifically the following code snippet

```
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
        proxyFactory.copyFrom(this);
        proxyFactory.setTarget(bean);
        if (!proxyFactory.isProxyTargetClass()) {
            evaluateProxyInterfaces(bean.getClass(), proxyFactory);
        }
        proxyFactory.addAdvisor(this.advisor);
        return proxyFactory.getProxy(getProxyClassLoader());
```

So seems like proxyFactory.getProxy will actually wipe out the value of the "num" field.

So I have created a simple test

```
    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
    proxyFactory.setTarget(new B());
    B proxiedB = proxyFactory.getProxy();
```

I can see proxiedB.num is 0 rather than 10.
I am not sure if the above proxying code make sense/wrote in the right way.

My question is that I am trying to understand why ProxyFactory.getProxy() would wipe out the information and how to get the original information from this proxied bean?

Comment: Because it is a proxy and in this case a class based proxy. Your `num` field is now uninitialized because it gets to the uninitialized proxy (that is a dynamic class generated class). If you would simply make the field private and create a `getNum()` method it would work as it would pass the call to the underlying object. Another reason why you should protect your privates :).

Comment: @M.Deinum ah thanks I didn't know that.

Comment: @M.Deinum another QQ, is there anyway I can get the original object's public field's values?

Comment: i have figured out myself. casting to org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised so that i can get the original object.